# Unable to give Cloud Functions Admin role to my account on Firebase's project setting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to set up the Firebase setting to link to FlutterFlow. I've followed the instruction, but I am unable to add the role for **Cloud Functions Admin**. When I started typing Cloud Functions in the search box, I could only come up with Cloud Functions Agent which is not the same thing. Please can anyone give me some advice on this? Many thanks!!

This is the screenshot of it shows when I tried to find Could Functions Admin

[image: 1]

I tried typing Cloud Functions Admin in the search box and the item should come up in the list as shown in the tutorial video, but it didn't happen on the Firebase list. I am just unable to find find the item. I could find the other item 'Service Account User' to add as a role, but not 'Cloud Functions Admin'.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of this issue is unknow. You can go to **Manage roles**, find Cloud Functions Admin and create a custom role out of it. Then you can add this role instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if functions is enabled for your project
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project//functions
I even had to press the 'Get Started' button.
Before that I had to upgrade my project plan from Spark (free plan) to Blaze (Pay as you go)
Then 'Cloud Functions Admin' appeared in the list.
I hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).